# how to post data with kotlin

Tags: post, http-post

i tried to post data to api with khttp but there is an error

this is my code

```
val payload = mapOf("review" to addReviewET.text, "rating" to quantity.toString(), "id_user" to "1", "id_movie" to id)
        val r = post(localhost.insertReview(), data = payload)
        println(r.text)
```

but it doesn't work it says error like this

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.mqa.android.moviereview, PID: 23984
              android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1448)
                  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:169)
                  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:139)
                  at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:136)
                  at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
                  at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.exhausted(RealBufferedSource.java:60)
                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.isHealthy(RealConnection.java:361)
                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:137)
                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
                  at khttp.responses.GenericResponse$Companion$defaultEndInitializers$1.invoke(GenericResponse.kt:90)
                  at khttp.responses.GenericResponse$Companion$defaultEndInitializers$1.invoke(GenericResponse.kt:32)
                  at khttp.responses.GenericResponse$connection$2.invoke(GenericResponse.kt:164)
                  at khttp.responses.GenericResponse$connection$2.invoke(GenericResponse.kt:30)
                  at khttp.responses.GenericResponse.openRedirectingConnection$khttp(GenericResponse.kt:124)
                  at khttp.responses.GenericResponse.getConnection(GenericResponse.kt:163)
                  at khttp.responses.GenericResponse.getRaw(GenericResponse.kt:207)
                  at khttp.responses.GenericResponse.getContent(GenericResponse.kt:216)
                  at khttp.responses.GenericResponse.init$khttp(GenericResponse.kt:350)
                  at khttp.KHttp.request(KHttp.kt:59)
                  at khttp.KHttp.post(KHttp.kt:48)
                  at khttp.KHttp.post$default(KHttp.kt:47)
                  at com.mqa.android.moviereview.module.activity.AddActivity$showMovieList$3.invokeSuspend(AddActivity.kt:90)
                  at com.mqa.android.moviereview.module.activity.AddActivity$showMovieList$3.invoke(Unknown Source:40)
                  at org.jetbrains.anko.sdk27.coroutines.Sdk27CoroutinesListenersWithCoroutinesKt$onClick$1$1.invokeSuspend(ListenersWithCoroutines.kt:300)
                  at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:32)
                  at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask$DefaultImpls.run(Dispatched.kt:235)
                  at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedContinuation.run(Dispatched.kt:81)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

what is this error exactly? and how to make it right? or if you have other way please let me know. thank you

i got the way from [here](https://khttp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you want to run the http request on the main thread.

There are two way to avoid this error.

1. Disable strict mode, which means you can run the request on the main thread.
2. Make the request with AsyncTask. This is the recommended way, however it involves some job to do and look for the results by having the app state under control.